# Subtract two columns, with each other as a condition, and append values

Tags: vba, excel

I need to subtract two columns from a large array and see which ones are positive and of those positive values I need to find the positive values row and append a few things onto that value.

Here is the general concept I'm thinking so far

> While < 8000
>   if (cell(i,1).Value - cell(i,2) > 0)
>   print in another sheet cell(i,3).value (cell(i,2).Value-cell(i,4)) cell.value(i,4)

for example...
suppose I have something like this
[2 2 hi yo]
[3 2 go mo]

this macro would return "go 1 mo" in another sheet.

```
Sub Leaves()
Dim i As Integer
Dim g As Integer
Dim Quantity As Integer
Dim Executed As Integer
Dim Leaves As Integer

i = 1
g = 1

Do While i < 8000
    Quantity = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 3).value
    Executed = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 5).value
    Leaves = Quantity - Executed
    If Leaves > 0 Then
        Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(g, 1).value = _
            Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 9).value & _
            Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 2).value & _
            Leaves & Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 3).value
        g = g + 1
    End If
    i = i + 1
Loop

End Sub
```

The above code gives me a `Type mismatch` error.

Comment: Sub Leaves()
Dim i As Integer
Dim g As Integer
Dim Quantity As Integer
Dim Executed As Integer
Dim Leaves As Integer
i = 1
g = 1
    Do While i < 8000
        Quantity = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 3).value
        Executed = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 5).value
        Leaves = Quantity - Executed
        If Leaves > 0 Then
        Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(g, 1).value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 9).value & Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 2).value & Leaves & Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 3).value
        g = g + 1
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Loop
End Sub

Comment: I am now getting a mismatch error for some reason.

Comment: To include code *add it to your question*.  Code in comments typically gets ignored.

Comment: What is the problem that you're having? Does the code above do what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is helpful if you say what line is throwing an error. Also, one should strive to create a [Minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The effort to do so often resolves the question before you need to post it.

The code itself seems fine and it runs for me (on an empty workbook) with no type mismatch. Thus, the problem must be with your assumptions about the spreadsheet.

Either of the lines

```
Quantity = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 3).value
Executed = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 5).value
```

will trigger a type mismatch if the corresponding value can't be converted to an integer. This could happen, for example, if one of the cells contains a string (other than something like "1") or an error value such as #N/A or #Value!.

The line which begins

```
Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(g, 1).value = _
```

will throw a type mismatch if one of the values being concatenated can't be converted to a string. An error value in one of the cells is the most likely culprit. If this is the case and for some reason you actually want to create a string that includes substrings which look like e.g. "#N/A" then you could use the `Text` property of those cells rather than `Value`.